# Using the delivery_estimate to get Estimated Daily Results with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've tried generating a HTTP entry, but it's only showing me estimate_dau and estimate_mau, but it's not showing me daily outcomes curve.

I was hoping to see more of something like this:

```
{  "data": [
{
  "bid_estimate": {
    "min_bid": 25,
    "median_bid": 39,
    "max_bid": 62
  },
  "daily_outcomes_curve": [
    {
      "spend": 0,
      "reach": 0,
      "impressions": 0,
      "actions": 0
    },
    {
      "spend": 265,
      "reach": 8243.6443831081,
      "impressions": 10350.320895139,
      "actions": 156.50895237165
    },
    {
      "spend": 526,
      "reach": 18251.053723186,
      "impressions": 22749.898172632,
      "actions": 240.93947618433
    },
    {
      "spend": 765,
      "reach": 28407.177135996,
      "impressions": 33619.733342562,
      "actions": 346.99329322783
    },
```

Here's the request I made:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_{ad account id}/delivery_estimate?targeting_spec=%7B%22geo_locations%22%3A%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22PH%22%5D%7D%2C%22age_min%22%3A21%2C%22age_max%22%3A21%2C%22publisher_platforms%22%3A%5B%22facebook%22%5D%2C%22facebook_positions%22%3A%5B%22feed%22%5D%2C%22device_platforms%22%3A%5B%22mobile%22%2C%22desktop%22%5D%2C%22interests%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%226002839660079%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Cosmetics%22%2C%7D%5D%7D&optimization_goal=REACH&access_token={access token}
```

But this is the only response I get:

```
{   "data": [
  {
     "daily_outcomes_curve": [
        {
           "spend": 0,
           "reach": 0,
           "impressions": 0,
           "actions": 0
        }
     ],
     "estimate_dau": 1316892,
     "estimate_mau": 1800000,
     "estimate_ready": true
  }
```

Comment: use this same api with adset id instead of the ad account id.
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/adset_id}/delivery_estimate?

Comment: The problem is how to calculate the estimates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this same API with adset id instead of the ad account id. `graph.facebook.com/v7.0/adset_id}/delivery_estimate?`

Answer (score -2):

The daily_outcomes_curve field will only have data when Facebook is able to provide high confidence predictions. When Facebook does not have high confidence predictions it will return an array of 1 point with all 0s.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/delivery_estimate/)